# Stop TradtionalForm evaluating expression

Tags: evaluation, traditional-form

I'm trying to get this expression to  display as typed instead of evaluating the 1/1.121.

```
SetAttributes[TraditionalForm, NHoldAll];
TraditionalForm[(17.517*CuS^2 - 12.081*CuS + 54.875)/(1.121)]
```

After reading the documentation I would have thought NHoldAll would have stopped this but it doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct attribute to set would be `HoldAll`, but modifying built-in functions like this (setting attributes that affect evaluation) is very likely to break things.

Instead, use `HoldForm`:

```
TraditionalForm@HoldForm[(17.517*CuS^2 - 12.081*CuS + 54.875)/(1.121)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Much appreciated.